# Accessing the columns of pivot table in Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, data-science, pandasql

I'm using a python pandas pivot. How can I get access the columns of pivot on new data frame?

```
KM_pivot_first = pd.pivot_table(read_sql_KM, values=["IMPRESSIONS","ENGAGEMENTS"],index="PLACEMENT_ID",aggfunc=np.sum)

KM_data_summary = KM_pivot_first[["PLACEMENT_ID", "IMPRESSIONS", "ENGAGEMENTS"]]
```

error:

> File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line
>   1231, in _convert_to_indexer
>       raise KeyError('%s not in index' % objarr[mask]) KeyError: "['PLACEMENT_ID'] not in index"

though, 'PLACEMENT_ID' is present in the query.

Comment: Can you provide a sample data ?

Comment: The only thing I want to merge two pivot data frames on the index.

Comment: Check the 'PLACEMENT_ID' column. There can be missing data.

Comment: thanks for the response, reset index worked here.